# pesquisar lista de objetos no Entity [LINQ]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tenho uma lista de objetos e gostaria de pesquisar 2 propriedades dessa lista no banco de dados. se que com uma lista de tipos primitivos eu faria assim:

```
(from n in db.Tabela
 where listaPrimitivos.Contains(n.propriedade)
 select n)
```

Pensei como faria a pesquisa da lista de objetos em SQL:

```
SQL = "Select * from Tabela where 1!=1"
for(int i = 0; i < listaObjetos.Count; i++){
    SQL += " or (Tabela.prop1 = " + listaObjetos.prop1
    SQL += "     and Tabela.prop2 = " + listaObjetos.prop2 + ") "
}
```

Como posso fazer essa mesma consulta usando o Entity Framework?

Comment: transforme as duas propriedades da sua lista em listas de tipos primitivos. :)

Answer (score 1):

Veja se ajudar

```
var prop1Lista = listaPrimitivos.Select(x => x.Propriedade1).tolist();
var prop2Lista = listaPrimitivos.Select(x => x.Propriedade2).tolist();

var result = db.Tabela
         .Where(t=> prop1Lista 
                         .Any(lp=> lp == t.propriedade1)
                    && prop2Lista 
                         .Any(lp=> lp == t.propriedade2));
```

Comment: Convertento para VB: `Dim query = db.TAB_FinanceiroTitulos.Where(Function(x) ListaNumero.Any(Function(y) x.NumeroControleOrigem.Equals(y.Numero) And x.Sequencia = y.Parcela))`

Comment: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'FN_ConciliacaoRecebimentoVendasMarketplace+TituloB2WConsulta'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context'

Comment: heheh foi o que pensei o Entity Framework não sabe mandar a lista de objeto para o banco, você vai ter que criar duas listas mesmo do tipo primitivo para cada propriedade do sseu objeto.

Comment: Ma e como vou saber que o indice 0 da primeira lista é o indice 0 da segunda?

Comment: prq você precisar sabe do index ? o primeiro  .Where(t=>  vai vare as duas listas para cada elemento da tabela .